# Typescript - Transform OneOf<A, B, C> to union A | B | C

Tags: typescript

Context: [Typegen](https://typegen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html) and [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) outputs the following typescript code

```
export interface IView
{
  actions: OneOf<CreateAction, DeleteAction>
}
```

The equivalent of `OneOf<CreateAction, DeleteAction>` in Typescript is `CreateAction | DeleteAction`.

Could we make a Typescript Type called "OneOf" to do this transformation, for any number of generics (not only 2 like CreateAction and DeleteAction) ?

I have used a regex to transform the code before executing it, but it would be easier to avoid this poststep.

I have also found a solution using [TupleToUnion](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/tuple-to-union.d.ts) (npm package type-fest), but it requires to add `[` and `]`

```
export interface IView
{
  actions: TupleToUnion<[CreateAction, DeleteAction]>
}
```

Comment: You can't make a *variadic* generic type, so if there are an arbitrary number of type arguments it won't work. Maybe if you have some reasonable maximum? What are the limits of the use cases?

Comment: Thanks! My use case has already six types, and it could grow to a dozen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because TypeScript doesn't have the capability to have "variadic type arguments"—the idea where you can provide an arbitrary number of arguments—this is probably the best approximation you can get:

```js
type OneOf<T1, T2 = never, T3 = never, T4 = never, T5 = never, T6 = never, T7 = never, T8 = never, T9 = never, T10 = never> = T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 | T6 | T6 | T7 | T8 | T9 | T10;

type NumberOrString = OneOf<string, number>; // string | number
type StringArrayOrRecordOrSymbol = OneOf<string[], Record<string, unknown>, symbol>; // string[] | Record<string, unknown> | symbol
```

In the example I've given I filled it in for up to 10 elements but the place where you stop is arbitrary. The trick at play here is that the default of every type parameter after `T1` is `never` and one of the special properties of `never` is that `T | never` reduces to just `T`.

This is because one of `never`'s intended usages is for a function that *never* returns (e.g. always throws an exception or stays in an infinite loop). To explain that, suppose you have a function `divide(numerator: number, denominator: number)` and let's say that divide will throw when `denominator` is `0`. This means sometimes the function will never return and other times it will divide and return `number` so the return type can be thought of as `never | number`.

However if you do `const result = divide(x, y);` you know the type of `result` is `number` because `divide` must have returned without an exception. Therefore `never | number` can be treated identically to `number`. To my knowledge TypeScript always does this reduction from `never | T` to `T` eagerly and it definitely will in this case.

Comment: It works to discrimate between types, thank you!
However the typehint onHover still displays "never" but it's ok
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcygXigbwFBSqSAuKAIgBNFCsoAzCCYAgOwFcBbAIwgCcBuDAXwwy5oAYQCGwFOgpCChAMbjy2ABZxGHAM4B5SgGUANjTAMW7bn0HhoW+hB0AeACoBGADRRHAJkm2Abp3dHAGYfCH8OQIAWUPDAgFYYgI8ANkSIjwB2NMCADmyPAE58lwAGNIA+SRcoAB8Pbzrg2o9oxoTG1I7mxyzGvMaixucSngw5OHoNCQRaAEl6SjhJAApRegBLZlF9Ahs7Snt4BHcxYHKAShRyjExsdcooVY2t-QA6IRRkVHlFc4pb7BQDi0dT0KBrTbbV6qdTaPSGCBgHjYfjYYHAUHg55Q6i0Hj8MYTDRwQyvfSIZYzYDzRbLNAyIgKYCEdwwzQ6AxGAjDXjnc48caTEkQMkUqk0uB0hkkMjuXF0KCRXn8gQYIA